# How to debug unexpected instance termination on Google Cloud Computing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I have a mongo database running on a Google Cloud Computing instance. For the second time now (in a few months), the server unexpectedly shut down into mode "TERMINATED". How do I find the cause of the shutdown?

The serial console just says, "The resource 'projects/my-project/zones/europe-west1-b/instances/mongo-db' is not ready".

I looked into the database logs, seems it received an external signal to shut down ("got signal 15 (Terminated)").

Nothing suspicious in the syslogs or messages logs after spinning up a new instance on the same disk. Also, there was no planned maintenance as far as I'm aware.

Any idea where to look?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your mongo database actually received a terminate signal, your instance was probably shutdown gracefully somehow. It sounds like something related to automatic migrations, but there are a couple of things to look at to help narrow this down.

1. In the Google Developers Console go to Compute -> Compute Engine -> VM instances -> mongo-db. There should be a section called "Availability policies." Check "On host maintenance" to make sure "Migrate VM instance" is selected. Otherwise, the VM will shutdown instead of migrating for maintenance.
2. You can also look at the operations for an instance at Compute -> Compute Engine -> Operations. This has all the operations that you and the system performed for your instances. You may see something around the time that the process terminated. You can also see this with the gcloud CLI with `gcloud compute operations list`

Comment: Thanks, there was indeed some more information to be found in the operations list:  
  
kind: compute#operation  
operationType: compute.instances.hostError  
statusMessage: Instance terminated by Compute Engine.  
user: system  
  
The "Migrate VM instance" on host maintenance option was enabled. So, apparently Compute Engine triggered this shutdown, and then failed to restart?

Comment: It might be that you were hit by this issue on 9/17? [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-operations/1uw-qEqjBdo) There's also some more information about migrations at the docs site [link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/zones#maintenance)

Comment: Yes, we were hit by that issue in September; just that the same kind of event happened again a few days ago.